# Joomla component publish/unpublish option not working in front-end

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

I have custom created Joomla component on my website, when I trying to unpublish some item of this component, seems that everything is OK, but in the front-end the unpublished item is still visible.

My Joomla site is vj3.8.8, but I have the same problem on the old Joomla versions too, J33 etc.

The website running in PHP5.6 environment.

In the Joomla "Global Configuration" I've changed to Development, but there is no any PHP error related to this component.

What should be the problem?
Which part/file of a Joomla component contain the function which control front-end publish/unpublished function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You said you created this component but you dont know where the publish unpublish code is. How strange?

Comment: I said " I have custom created Joomla component on my website" this means the component not exist on JED.
I never said that this component is created by me.

Comment: Where is the link? Without seeing the component even god cannot tell you where the publish unpublished code is. The developer only can tell. But if he followed Joomla coding guidelines then it is supposed to be in Model folder.

Comment: Make sure you are not logged in.

Comment: it's impossible to help you without seeing the code of the component. If the developer followed the guidelines, it would be in the models having the same name of the views though.